# Shell script :: Reading a column from file & store it in array

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, shell-scripting

I am working on shell script where i want to store O/P of the command in array.
I have a file containing rows & columns from where i want to extract 3rd column & store all values in a array. if suppose i have below in my file `info.txt`

```
  abc  xyz  pqr  akl
  mnt  var  man  lak
  qer  tag  sam  bob
```

I want to store pqr, man and sam in array lets call `name[1], name[2], name [3]`

Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do:

```
  name=( $(awk '{print $3}' ./info.txt) )
```

I find this a little simpler.  You can then access the array like ${name[1]} ${name[2]} or use * instead of a number for all elements.

Answer (score 6):

```
name=( $(cut -d ' ' -f 3 "./info.txt") )
```

will do what you want (starting with index 0 however).